# why image.copy() return None

Tags: python, image, numpy, machine-learning, opencv

```
import numpy as np

def getSkewAngle(cvImage) -> float:
    # Prep image, copy, convert to gray scale, blur, and threshold
    newImage = cvImage.copy()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(newImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (9, 9), 0)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    # Apply dilate to merge text into meaningful lines/paragraphs.
    # Use larger kernel on X axis to merge characters into single line, cancelling out any spaces.
    # But use smaller kernel on Y axis to separate between different blocks of text
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (30, 5))
    dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=2)

    # Find all contours
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)
    for c in contours:
        rect = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        x,y,w,h = rect
        cv2.rectangle(newImage,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

    # Find largest contour and surround in min area box
    largestContour = contours[0]
    print (len(contours))
    minAreaRect = cv2.minAreaRect(largestContour)
    cv2.imwrite("../img/boxes.jpg", newImage)
    # Determine the angle. Convert it to the value that was originally used to obtain skewed image
    angle = minAreaRect[-1]
    if angle < -45:
        angle = 90 + angle
    return -1.0 * angle
```

```
def rotateImage(cvImage, angle: float):
    newImage = cvImage.copy()
    (h, w) = newImage.shape[:2]
    center = (w // 2, h // 2)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)
    newImage = cv2.warpAffine(newImage, M, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
    return newImage
```

```
def deskew(cvImage):
    angle = getSkewAngle(cvImage)
    return rotateImage(cvImage, -1.0 * angle)
```

```
new = cv2.imread("../img/incliné.png")
```

```
fixed = deskew(new)  # error :'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

I tried to use np.copy(img) but it doesn't work
I tried to pass the path of image and use imread inside of the function but it does'nt work too
why cvImage.copy() return none and i had already used imread

Comment: Please post the full error message. Your summary just doesn't give enough information.

Comment: The problem isn't that `cvImage.copy` is returning `None`; it's that `cvImage` itself appears to *be* `None`, and it's not clear how that could happen.

Comment: At the very front of `deskew` add `assert cvImage is not None, "need image"`. You do `fixed = deskew(new)` - so its `new` that is `None`. Whatever created `new` is the problem.